# How to display tabset again after .close()?

Tags: python, ipywidgets

I am working on a small application on ipywidgets that has multiple frames. This means users can click a button, and then the original set of widgets will be closed and a new set of widgets will appear. The function which I am using has a simplified structure as below:

```
def to_next_page(x):
    current_page.close()
    display(next_page)
```

I have a button in current_page that goes to next_page, and vice versa. When I tried to go back from next_page to current_page, the following message appeared instead of the widget:

```
Tab(children=(VBox(children=(Text(value='', description='Username:'), Password(description='Password:'), Button(description='Login', style=ButtonStyle()), Button(description='Forget Password', style=ButtonStyle()))), VBox(children=(Text(value='', description='Username:'), Password(description='Password:'), Button(description='Login', style=ButtonStyle()), Button(description='Forget Password', style=ButtonStyle()), Button(description='Sign up', style=ButtonStyle())))), _titles={'0': 'Staff', '1': 'Member'})
```

Is there any way to go back and forth between widget sets? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

you cant use .close

use this

```
out = Output()
def to_next_page(x):
    out.clear_output()
    with out:
        display(next_page)
```

and for displaying everytime use:

```
with out:
    display(anything)
```

and for closing use:

```
    out.clear_output()
```